# Connect multiple view controllers from storyboard to code in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created multiple view controllers on storyboard. Now I wanna create several view controller .m and .h files to represent these view controllers respectively. How do I connect the file to its correspondent view controllers?  For instance, there are 2 view controllers created and I wanna connect FirstViewController.m file to the first view controllers and connect SecondViewController.m file to the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the controller, go to the identity inspector, and change the class from UIViewController to your custom class, which should show up in the pull down menu..

Answer (score 1):

ViewControllers on storyboard can have the same class and you can have different models for each.

*now it depends on your needs :*

- Panel Utility (on left)

  - identity inspector (3rd from left to right)
  - chose your class or let the default one if you don't need